# Best approach to calling a second controller function within a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My route specifies the function show().

```
/**
 * Finds the primary photo within JSON product field
 * 
 * @param $product
 * @return string
 */
public function primaryPhoto($product) {

    // decode JSON

    return $photo;
}

/**
 * Grabs necessary products for detailed product view
 * 
 * @param $sku
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($sku) {

    $product = // products by sku

    $related = // related products for $product

    return view('cart.product', compact('product', 'related'));
}
```

Above is the relevant code for my controller. The function primaryPhoto takes an output from the function show() and retrieves the primary photo in a serialised blob.

Originally this function primaryPhoto was in the blade view but seems a bit messy to have functions in the view.

I want to know the best way to call the function from the view and still be able to pass it either of the parameters $product or $related.

```
{!! primaryPhoto($product) !!}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate all the help. I actually found a suitable response from elsewhere.

I took the method out of the controller and instead created an app/helpers.php file following this [demonstration](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/50/creating-a-helpers-file)

This makes it globally available.

Answer (score 0):

Having a function in the controller, and then expecting to call is a bad idea, according to me, there are these things you can do :

1. Add a method to the Product model,say `image()` and use `$this` inside the method to process and echo or return the image.

   ```
   class Product extends Eloquent
   {
       //other stuff
       function primaryPhoto()
       {
           //Process and return
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define a function in your `routes.php` file for processing the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an accessor on your Product model.

```
class Product {
  public function getPrimaryPhotoAttribute($value) {
    // decode JSON
    return $photo;
  }
}
```

Then you can just do this in the view:

```
{{ $product->primaryPhoto }}
{{ $related->primaryPhoto }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* be trying to call other controller methods from a view. A controller passes its data to a view; a view does not ask controller methods for data.

Instead, grab the primary photo in your controller action and then pass that to your view along with your other data:

```
public function show($sku)
{
    $product = Product::findBySku();

    $primaryPhoto = $this->primaryPhoto($product);

    $related = Product::relatedTo($product);

    return view('cart.product', compact('primaryPhoto', 'product', 'related'));
}
```

However, if a product has a primary photo, I’d add that to your `Product` model.